# have comment for table in MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, workbench

I create some table in MySQL workbench but they don't have comment now is there any way to have it ???
notice : I want comment for table not column

Comment: `ALTER TABLE tableName COMMENT = 'This is just to test how to alter comments';`

Comment: @zohre Please provide a feedback on one of the answers if the question is closed. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

create comment on table

```
create table (...) comment='table_comment';
```

Display comments by:

```
show table status where name='table_name';
```

Edit

```
ALTER TABLE test_comments COMMENT = 'another comment';
```